# 'Case' statement

Tags: sql

I have a table called sales.Customer, customertype is one of the column in

that. It have values like 'S', 'I'.

```
select 
case CustomerType
when 's' then 'SUPER USER'
end as name
from sales.Customer
```

From the above query I am getting 'SUPER USER' for customertype 'S' but other CustomerType it's showing as NULL.

My case is written only to check for 'S' , so for the remaining it should just display the Customertype. Why it's not doing so.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have `else` block

```
case CustomerType when 's' 
then 'SUPER USER' 
ELSE CustomerType           -- << this 
end
```

Comment: Why else part  is needed. My case specifies only 'S' for remaining it should just display what it's available in the column.

Comment: no, you have to specify the value for nonmatching condition. if it does not meet your condition, it will display `null` as default value.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way where I can get the non-matching column value as same. I don't want null.

Comment: Having the "ELSE CustomerType" will cover what you are asking, unless [CustmerType] itself has a null value, for which case, you can also override null value with: "ELSE ISNULL(CustomerType,'ABC')"

Comment: Nope, IMOO. Will there by any problem if you just add `ELSE` block? :D

Comment: I just curious to know is there any way I can get same values instead of "NULL"  for the column which are not matching with case statement.